I cannot import androidx.compose.runtime.collect in kotlin android studio
the .collect part of the import stays red. I have checked for typos, checked my jetpack compose version and I have invalidated my cache and restarted android studio, but the error didn't disappear. How can I solve this issue?
I am using collect in this function:
import androidx.compose.runtime.collect

fun startLocationUpdates() {
            locationUpdateScope.launch {
                location.collect { locationData: LocationData -> // Collect changes in location state
                    if (locationData != null) {
                        user.longitude = locationData.longitude
                        user.latitude = locationData.latitude
                        networkManager.UpdateLocation(user)
                        delay(timeMillis = 5000L) // Delay between updates// Pass location to updateLocation
                    }
                }
            }
        }


I'm not aware there exists a function androidx.compose.runtime.collect.
If location is a Flow you can use this instead:
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect

If location is a Compose State then you shouldn't try to observe it directly. Just use it in a @Composable function and let the compose runtime manage that automatically.
